# Asp.net MVC Post JSon data from one to another?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, post, acceptverbs

I have Three projects in one solution (two are asp.net MVC type and last one is class type); call it EmployeeMVC Proj and TimeSheetMVC Proj (To manage the views) and Third one EntityLib proj.

Now from EmployeeMVC Proj; I would like to pup-up a page from TimeSheetMVC Proj and perform some operations. Let's say from EmployeeMVC Proj Post Time-Sheet Data in JSon format to TimeSheetMVC Proj and get back the result.

How can we achieve this?

Many thanks,
Jigar

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the the two MVC projects will be hosted in their own web applications so the EmployeeMVC application can just post a form to an action on a controller in the TimesheetMVC application.